# CSS/Bootstrap can't get styling right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I using this with bootstrap. Tables display fine but theres something wrong with the width of the thead and tbody rows, you can see they have a smaller width than the entire column.

IF you click the panel head you'll see the line temporarily being the correct size. How do I fix this.

```
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <!-- Default panel contents -->
                    <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1">Shop 1</div>
                    <!-- Table -->
                    <table class="table collapse" id="collapse1">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Number</th>
                                <th>Description</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody> 
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row">1</th>
                                <td>this is a shop</td>
                                <td><a href="#">Go to</a></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well your problem is that the no. of columns i.e. `<th></th>` elements in table head `<thead>` doesn't match the no. of columns in table body `<tbody>`.

So you need to put an extra `<th></th>` inside table head `<thead>` which could be blank like this -

[Your code Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ManojSalvi/Lk1fucqe/)

[Updated Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ManojSalvi/v6mntwzs/) with code below -

```
       <div class="panel panel-default">
            <!-- Default panel contents -->
            <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1">Shop 1</div>
            <!-- Table -->
            <table class="table collapse" id="collapse1">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Number</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody> 
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row">1</th>
                        <td>this is a shop</td>
                        <td><a href="#">Go to</a></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```